Error trying to create a classification model using Tensorflow and Keras in R
I'm trying to create a model for classifying images based on an already existing model (xception). The first time the code worked and it gave me the structure of the model but then when I went to train it RStudio crashed (to be expected). Since then I haven't changed that part of the code but it won't work anymore.
This is the code:

mod_base <- application_xception(weights = 'imagenet',
                                 include_top = FALSE, input_shape = c(width, height, 3))
freeze_weights(mod_base)
model_function <- function(learning_rate = 0.001,
                           dropoutrate=0.2, n_dense=1024){
  k_clear_session()
  model <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
    mod_base %>%
    layer_global_average_pooling_2d() %>%
    layer_dense(units = n_dense) %>%
    layer_activation("relu") %>%
    layer_dropout(dropoutrate) %>%
    layer_dense(units=output_n, activation="softmax")
  model %>% compile(
    loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
    optimizer = optimizer_adam(lr = learning_rate),
    metrics = "accuracy"
  )
  return(model)
}
  
model <- model_function()
model

When I run it I get the following error:
Error during wrapup: ValueError: Inputs to a layer should be tensors. Got '' (of type <class 'keras.src.models.sequential.Sequential'>) as input for layer 'xception'.
Run reticulate::py_last_error() for details.
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
Browse[1]> model
Error during wrapup: object 'model' not found
I was expecting the code to return a structure of the model created using the model function that I have created by using the model exception.
